# titanium-mobile reading an iPhone stack trace

Tags: iphone, titanium, stack-trace

I have no idea how to interpret a stack trace console output for my iPhone app. Can anyone point me to a primer or other source that would help me decipher it? Here's the output in case you can explain the error. I'm interested also in learning how to read them on my own.

```
[ERROR] The application has crashed with an unhandled exception. Stack trace:

0   CoreFoundation                      0x023a158c __exceptionPreprocess + 156
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x024f5313 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x02359ef8 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
3   Foundation                          0x007063bb -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 116
4   UIKit                               0x00989e8b -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 8420
5   UIKit                               0x00978d36 -[UITableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:] + 56
6   mobiletributes-app                  0x0009ef7e -[TiUITableView dispatchAction:] + 7774
7   Foundation                          0x0068a94e __NSThreadPerformPerform + 251
8   CoreFoundation                      0x023828ff __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
9   CoreFoundation                      0x022e088b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 571
10  CoreFoundation                      0x022dfd86 __CFRunLoopRun + 470
11  CoreFoundation                      0x022df840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
12  CoreFoundation                      0x022df761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
13  GraphicsServices                    0x041a71c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
14  GraphicsServices                    0x041a7289 GSEventRun + 115
15  UIKit                               0x00919c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
16  mobiletributes-app                  0x0000473a main + 410
17  mobiletributes-app                  0x00003005 start + 53
```

Comment: Try to walk back on what you recently changed, and revert it bit by bit intil the error is gone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code execution is from bottom to top ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace)). without seeing any code it's difficult. you're adding a tableViewRow at a specific index and it fails:

```
[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] 
[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _endCellAnimationsWithContext:]
[UITableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:]
```

maybe you're adding a row at an invalid index or to a section that doesn't exist.

Comment: Because it is titanium, the stacktrace is based on code not written, but generated. He could show some JavaScript though, but usually it is unknown where the error came from

Comment: Thanks for the responses. My brain sorta locks up when I see hexadecimals and Obj-C methods spewed all over the place. Don't quite have the hang of that, yet.